# Missing Alias settings when calling bash withing a subprocess in python

Tags: python, linux, ldap, subprocess, alias

I placed a script in /etc/profile.d/

```
# default_dba.sh
if  groups | grep -qw "dba" ;
 then 
if [ $USER != "oracle" ]; then
. /u00/scripts/oracle_alias
fi
fi
```

The scipt sets aliases if the LDAP user is a member of the dba group.
This works.
The LDAP user starts a python script.
As a last step the python script calls a new bash shell

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i'], shell=True)
```

In that shell session there are the special aliases (created by the /u00/scripts/oracle_alias script) missing, just the default os aliases are there.

Can I fix this without creating home directories for LDAP users?

Answer (score 0):

The startup files (under /etc/profile etc..) are read only when the shell is invoked as 'login' shell. eg:- bash -l

See 'INVOCATION' section under man bash for more details.

snippet (from man page)

```
When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive  login  shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, 
it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  
After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order,
and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```